# Multiindex scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter

Suppose I have the following data:

```
data = {'Value': {('1', 1): 3.0,
('1', 2): 4.0,
('1', 3): 51.0,
('1', 4): 10.0,
('1', 5): 2.0,
('1', 6): 17.0,
('1', 7): 14.0,
('1', 8): 7.0,
('1', 9): 2.0,
('1', 10): 1.0}}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Let's say this represents values for something for the first ten days in January.  I want to plot this data, so I use:

```
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Now, suppose I have another data set that has values for a subset of these dates with slightly different values but the same index values:

```
df1 = df[df['Value']<10]
df1['Value'] = df1['Value']*2
```

My question is, how can I overlay a scatter plot of this data on the original line graph?

Comment: I don't use pandas, but what I do is I just add the `plt.show()` after I plot all my data. It then plots all of it in a single plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the axes handle of the first plot, then reindex df1 to align the data with the same indexes as df and plot df1 using `ax=ax`.

```
ax = df.plot()
df1.reindex(df.index).plot(marker='o',linestyle='none',color='g', ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]